# Spacing between the y-axis values in highchart

Tags: php, highcharts

I am generating a graph using High-chart which is like - [image]

Here i want to have space between y-axis values (2510G-48, 2530ya-24G etc)

How I can do this ?
I tired using **tickPixelInterval** but it does not seem to work with y-axis.

Code is-

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"> </script>
    <script>
$(function () {
    js_platform = <?php echo json_encode($platform); ?>;
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Overall avalibility of testcases on each platform'
            },
            xAxis: {
            tickPixelInterval: 9000,
                categories: js_platform,
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'TestCase Count',
                    align: 'high'
                },

            },


            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -40,
                y: 100,
                floating: true,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                shadow: true
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                data:  [<?php echo join($totalTest, ',') ?>]
            }]
        });
    });
    </script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: I think its just a matter of too many lines to draw on a specific surface. Have you tried to increase the height of the div? It would have more surface area to use then. You can just do that with a style="height: 600px" in the div.

Comment: yea.. exactly.. such a stupid thing I have asked :(

Comment: No worries. Is it okay if I make an answer out of my comment so you can accept it? We all like the reputation ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably just make the chart-container higher.

Your issue is more due to a lack of "surface" to draw on than a configuration parameter.

Just modify the containing div with a style. For example:

`<div id="chart" style="height: 600px"></div>`